# .net framework 5 not appearing in visual studio

Tags: .net, frameworks, visual-studio-2019

I have installed .net framework 5 SDK and updated visual studio community to 16.8.1 (and restarted) but the framework does not appeaaring in options for any project or when creating new.
Any help?

Comment: It is .NET 5 not .NET framework. .NET 5 has merged both .net framework and .net core into one; from now on there will only be one .net
First full public complete version released on November 2020 @ https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: Thank yoy. I checked the link. It has been released at 10/11/2020. I downloaded and installed but nothing happens :)

Comment: Sorry. I was not too clear. .net core 5 is appearing in asp but not at winforms apps

Comment: Your question still not very clear.
1) You must be using VS 2019
2) Alternatively you can create the basic code structure using dotnet new command
I would say, create a new project again from VS or CLI commands and continue. You may create a new prj files and re-add your source files too. when you create ensure that you use .NET5